# Return multiple values from jquery ajax call to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to return multiple values from a php process.

Here is the jQuery function

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'shopping_cart_add.php',
    data: 'item_id='+subscription_id+'&item_name='+subscription_name+'&item_price='+subscription_price,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response, statusText) {
                var qty = response.item_quantity;
                $("#shopping-cart-quantity").html(qty);
    }
});
```

The above seems to work except I can't retrieve the specific field values from the returned JSON.

When I try this...

```
var qty = response.item_quantity;
$("#shopping-cart-quantity").html(qty);
```

Nothing happens.

If I change...

```
$("#shopping-cart-quantity").html(qty);
```

to

```
$("#shopping-cart-quantity").html(response);
```

I get the following...

```
{ 'account_id': '1', 'item_id' : 'cce3d2a017f6f1870ce8480a32506bed', 'item_name' : 'CE', 'item_quantity' : '1', 'item_price' : '1' }
```

Comment: Does `response` have a `responseJSON` property that has the object you're looking for?

Comment: @ScottKaye Since he's using `dataType: 'json'`, `response` is already parsed, it's not the XHR.

Comment: Your JSON is incorrect. Strings **must** be contained in double quotes, not single quotes. You have a bug in your PHP script, it's not calling `json_encode()` to encode the response.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are using json_encode() for returning result array

```
/*** PHP ***/
echo json_encode($resultArr); exit ;
```

And in AJAX  try with eval() to access response text value .

```
/*** AJAX ***/
var qty = eval(response.item_quantity);
```